# Meaning of passage

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following passage?

> I don’t know what your odds are in the world as a whole, but as far as the population of this car goes? You’re a veritable Mack Daddy.

Comment: I think this depends on the context

Comment: well that's a part of the Big Bang Theory series  , In the last scene when Sheldon , Leonard , Howard  , Penny and Radesh in Car . Howard starts to sing and Sheldon says this to Leonard .

Comment: Now, I understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thursagen cited, a "mack daddy" is very good with the ladies, a womanizer, etc. Throughout the episode, Leonard has been hoping to start a relationship with Penny, and so far has failed. In the car with Howard the pervert, Raj the nervous mute, and Sheldon, he is the male with the best shot at a relationship with Penny. The quote boils down to: compared to all the other men in the world, Leonard has no chance with Penny, but compared only to the men in the car, his success is almost certain.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's break this sentence up.

Let's start with "Mack Daddy". According to the M-W Dictionary, a  "Mack Daddy" is:

> slang : a slick womanizer
>
> slang : one that is the best

Sheldon could have been meaning that Leonard was the best (at driving?) or at catching women. Sheldon may have said this due to something Leonard did previously. This something previously made Sheldon think that Leonard was the best at catching women.

The best at catching women? **In terms of what?** The phrase "I don't know what your odds are in the world as a whole, but as far as the population of this car goes?" limits this. That is, Leonard, is the "Mack Daddy" in the car only.  Sheldon doesn't know if Leonard is a Mack Daddy compared to the world, he only knows Leonard is a Mack Daddy compared to the other people in the car.

Comment: Does He mean Leonard Or Howard ?, since Sheldon talks to Leonard . and if he's talking to Leonard , Leonard is just Driving and Doing nothing specific to make him a man who catches women easily ,.

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the names. I don't watch that show, you see